# SVG icons don't always appear on Iphone 4

Tags: html, ios, css, svg

I'm having a weird problem with a website I made. I used many SVG icons in the project to increase front-end performance.

The problem I have is that some of my icons only show on Iphone 4 when I refresh the page about 3-4 times. When I go to another destination on the page, the problem appears again, and I can't see some of the icons. The icons that is buggy is some that is used in a modal and a slidedown div to reveal some extra features.

HTML:

```
<svg class="login-arrow">
    <use xlink:href="img/svg-system.svg#login-arrow"></use>
</svg>
```

CSS:

```
.login-arrow {
    width: rem(22);
    height: rem(21);
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -2;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-right: -50%;
    -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    fill: $white2;
}
```

SVG code:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<symbol id="login-arrow" viewBox="0 0 32.3 31">
        <title>Login ikon</title> 
        <desc>Pil der peger til højre og skal illustrerer at man logger ind på JustHome boligportal ved at klikke på pilen.</desc>
        <path d="M19,10.8l5,4l-1.2,1.6l-5-4L19,10.8z" />
        <path d="M15.4,20.6h-15v-10h15v2h-13v6h13V20.6z" />
        <path d="M13.4,30.7v-8.1h2v3.9l13.4-10.9L15.4,4.7v3.9h-2V0.5L32,15.6L13.4,30.7z" />
</symbol>
</svg>
```

Comment: This can be issue with svg and object type..please provide demo link or jsfiddle where we can check for more details.thank you

Comment: The link is justhome + TLD (.dk). The problem is when you press login at the top right. The svgs wont show on Iphone. Thanks:)

Comment: well!! where is href??

Comment: you means justhome.dk?

Comment: Yes :) Just trying not to get the link show up in search results with stackoverflow issue ;)

Comment: if you are talking about login icon(lock icon) then it appears in android and iphone but there is notification so you have to click on that and then you will see login icon.

Comment: Cool:) Does the icons inside the login modal work for you? The X for closing the login modal and the arrow icon in the modal?

Comment: yup...x is for closing and red arrow for submit.

Comment: nd they show up on your Iphone? Weird.. :/ Also if you refresh page?

Comment: yes they do..i have iPhone 5S and your icons are working great.

Comment: Your welcome. we are here to help..:)